# AWS cloud formation with CI/CD

Tags: amazon-web-services

From my research so far, it seems Atlassian is the only one that supports cloud formation stacks as part of the CI/CD pipeline. Most other tools like Drone, CodeShip etc seem to work with S3 for dropping the artifacts in a bucket.

Are there tools / plugins / projects that support AWS CF as part of CI/CD?

Answer (score 2):

There are Plugins or Add-Ons to Automate the CI / CD for [Bamboo ( Atlassian )](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.utoolity.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-aws-plugin) & [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWS+Cloudformation+Plugin) ( Or in the other words, I have seen ).

Until the respective CI/CD Repository Provider or the open source community comes up with a similar offering; **I guess you add additional step in the Build Process & Call the CloudFormation API and do the stack launch via. a web service call** [CFN - CreateStack](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html)

Answer (score 1):

one of the founders of [Codeship](http://codeship.io) here.

You can use the AWS tools to deploy your cloud formation stacks into AWS the same way you do on your own machine currently. We have a script deployment that lets you add any command you want to run for your deployment. So there are basically no limits to what you can do with Codeship there.

If you have further questions you can also always send a support request in our app which will help you quickly.